# failed to redirect when user is logged in from /login/shipping to /shipping

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I have this simple case, When a non logged in visitor add products to cart and then checkout, they will be redirected to login/register page, this case it's work normally. But when a logged in user add products to cart then checkout, it still redirect to localhost:3000/login/shipping, when it should be localhost:3000/shipping.

this is the CartScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Image,
  ListGroupItem,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Card,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../actions/cartActions";

export const CartScreen = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const history = useNavigate();

  const productId = id;
  const qty = search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  console.log(cartItems);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };
  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    history("/login?redirect=shipping");
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <Message>
            Your Cart is Empty <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <ListGroupItem key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <FormControl
                      as="select"
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </FormControl>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={(e) => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroupItem>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroupItem>
              <h2>
                SubTotal ({cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty, 0)})
                items
              </h2>
              $
              {cartItems
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn-block"
                disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                onClick={checkoutHandler}
              >
                Proceed to Checkout
              </Button>
            </ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default CartScreen;
```

There's a checkout button with onClick action to checkoutHandler function

```
const checkoutHandler = () => {
history("/login?redirect=shipping");
}
```

Idk if it's a backend problem or a simple redirect problem so these are the backend files that responsible to handle registration and login.

userController.js

```
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import generateToken from "../utils/generateToken.js";

// @desc Auth user & get token
// @route POST /api/users/login
// @access Public

const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
  }
});
// @desc Register new user
// @route POST /api/users
// @access Public

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("user already exists");
  }
  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("invalid user data");
  }
});

// @desc Get user profile
// @route GET /api/users/profile
// @access Private

const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

  if (user) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("No user found");
  }
});

// @desc Update user profile
// @route PUT /api/users/profile
// @access Private

const updateUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

  if (user) {
    user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
    if (req.body.password) {
      user.password = req.body.password;
    }

    const updatedUser = await user.save();

    res.json({
      _id: updatedUser._id,
      name: updatedUser.name,
      email: updatedUser.email,
      isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(updatedUser._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("No user found");
  }
});

export { authUser, getUserProfile, registerUser, updateUserProfile };
```

userRoutes.js

```
import express from "express";
import {
  authUser,
  getUserProfile,
  registerUser,
  updateUserProfile,
} from "../controllers/userController.js";
import { protect } from "../middleware/authMiddleware.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", authUser);
router.route("/").post(registerUser);
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);

export default router;
```

authMiddleware.js

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

const protect = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    let token
    
    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        try {
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
            //console.log(decoded)
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')
            //next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error ('Not authorization, token failed')
        }
    }
    if(!token){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("Not authorized, no token")
    }

    next()
})

export {protect}
```

these are the redux files responsible for register and login.

userActions.js

```
import {
  USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
  USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGOUT,
  USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
  USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";
import axios from "axios";

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login",
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.message && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
  localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOGOUT });
};

export const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
    });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users",
      { name, email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.message && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const getUserDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.message && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const updateUserProfile = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile`, user, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.message && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

userReducers.js

```
import {
  USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
  USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGOUT,
  USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
  USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const userRegisterReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_REGISTER_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_REGISTER_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const userDetailsReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, user: action.payload };
    case USER_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const userUpdateProfileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Just use only `history("/login");` once ?

Comment: so, no need to use ```history("login?redirect=shipping"```?

Comment: Just try once to see whether it works or not

Comment: nope, it redirects me back to product screen, which is "/"

Comment: what is your endpoint of login page? TO SEE - Go to login page and then paste the url here

Comment: that would be http://localhost:3000/Login

Comment: so just replace with `history("/Login");`

Comment: what i want is, if user is logged in, when they click the checkout button, it'll go ```history(localhost:3000/shipping)```, if user that is not logged in, when they click checkout, it'll go to ```history(localhost:3000/login)```. that's why i use ```history("/login?redirect=shipping)```. replacing it with ```history("/Login")``` will just redirect a logged in user back to "/", it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you can add a condition like this
`if(token) ? history("/shipping") : history("/Login");`

Comment: Have you tried `history("/login?redirect=/shipping")`

Comment: If you have your user state in redux, simply make the checkout button navigate to the correct route based on the auth state.

Comment: @john_smith have you figured this one out?

Answer (score 1):

I was having hard time with the same problem, and I solve it with changing the LoginScreen file, In the first I was getting the location value from window.location and that's the reason why it wasn't working for me, after changing the code in LoginScreen file from:

```
const location = window.location;
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '';
```

to:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const location = useLocation();
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `/login?redirect=shipping` with `/login?redirect=/shipping`

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Pawan Kumar